# jQuery finding closest image src to a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

if I have the following html:

```
<div class="showPin">
    <div class="pinIt" style="display: none;">
        <a href="#" onclick="window.open(&quot;http://pinterest.com/pin/create/button/?url=http://mysite.com/some-post&amp;description=Some Description&amp;media=http://mysite.com/path/to/myimage.jpg&quot;,&quot;Pinterest&quot;,&quot;scrollbars=no,menubar=no,width=600,height=380,resizable=yes,toolbar=no,location=no,status=no&quot;);return false;"><img src="images/pinbutton.jpg" class="pinbuttonImg"></a>
    </div>
    <a href="myimage.jpg">
        <img class="lazy data-lazy-ready" src="myimage.jpg" data-lazy-type="image" data-lazy-src="http://dev.papermusepress.com/stageblog/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/Fall_baby_shower_mantle2.jpg" alt="Fall Baby Shower Mantle" width="700" height="393" style="display: inline;">
    </a>
</div>
```

how can i get my alert function to work so it alerts the img src that is the actual image getting pinned, which has a `class="lazy"` always in it.

```
$('div.pinIt').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).closest('img.lazy').attr('src');      
    alert(url);
});
```

all it alerts for me is `undefined`.  what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$('div.pinIt').click(function() {
    var url = $(this).next('a').find('img.lazy').attr('src');      
    alert(url);
});
```

Closest `traverses thru the ancestors`.
But the image is inside the `sibling(anchor tag)` of the **div**. So try it this way..

If you want to use `.closest()` then this should work..

```
$('div.pinIt').click(function() {
        var url = $(this).closest('.showPin').find('img.lazy').attr('src');      
        alert(url);
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the easiest ways is to go up to parent and search for image element inside:

```
$("div.pinIt").click(function() {
    var url = $(this).closest("div.showPin").find("img.lazy").attr("src");
    alert(url);
});
```